# chamar api autenticada do laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, api, autenticação

bom dia, tudo bem?
Eu estou lendo uma api(que só pode ser acessada com autenticação do usuario) feita no laravel.
Para consumir esses dados, estou usando jquery/ajax.
Eu sei que preciso enviar um token para a api para poder acessa-la e para isso, estou usando o seguinte código :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': TokemMovies },
  method:'GET',  
  url:'http://localhost/testeEmprego/public/api/filmes',
  success:function(response){
    console.log(response.length);
    for(var i = 0; i< response.length; i++) 
           { 
               console.log(''+response[i].nome);
               $('.filmes').prepend(
                   "<li>"
                   +"<h3>"+response[i].nome+"</h3>"
                   +""+response[i].ano+""
                   +"<p>"+response[i].sinopse+"</p>"
                   +"<div><img src='"+endereco+""+response[i].imagem+"' alt=''></div>"
                   +"<div class='select'>"
                        +"<form class='likex'>"
                            +"<input type='hidden' class='filmeCod' name='filmeCod' value='"+response[i].id+"'>"
                            +"<label for='gostei_"+i+"'>gostei </label>"
                                +"<input id='gostei_"+i+"'    class='like' type='radio' value='1' name='like'>"
                            +"<label for='naoGostei_"+i+"'>não gostei</label>"
                                +"<input id='naoGostei_"+i+"' class='like' type='radio' value='0' name='like'>"
                        +"</form>"
                   +"</div>"
                   +"</li>"
                   );
           }
  },
```

porém, não consigo ler nada da api, ou seja, não devo estar enviando corretamente o token.
Enfim, o que acontece de errado aqui???
Obrigado a todos pela atenção!
Horácio

Comment: Confirme no header da sua request se o token está sendo enviado corretamente, se possível faça um teste com o mesmo token usando o postman.

Comment: então, mas nesse caso, o "X-CSRF-TOKEN" é o nome correto da variável que deve ser enviada para a api? ou para rotas de api autenticadas existe outro nome? o que tá me incomodando mais, é com qual nome de variável eu mando esse token...

Comment: Essa informação vai depender da sua API, por exemplo as API`s que eu costumo fazer eu utilizo o JWT, e o parâmetro usando no header é o Bearer.

Comment: eu usei o passport...

Comment: e sempre que tento acessar, aparece no console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)"

Answer (score 0):

Tava com esse problema alguns dias atrás resolvi da seguinte forma...

```
url:'http://localhost/testeEmprego/public/api/filmes?api_token='+Token_api
```

A variável `Token_Api` passo para ela o token via front-end e chamo ela em js quando precisa.